Maximizing accuracy with RTK/DGNSS
I have an Ardusimple simpleRTK2B and an SBG Ellipse D. I am trying to construct a rover-base station kind of system where the SBG Ellipse D is located on the Rover and simpleRTK2B on the base station. The SBG is able to send Raw GPS Data via ROS2 only and simpleRTK is able to get a RTK fix at 2.5 meters accuracy( after a lot of time though).
How can I maximize the accuracy that I get for the rover? It would be great if I can get sub-meter accuracy.

Please how did you integrate the simpleRTK with ROS2?

Based on what I have got working, I configured simpleRTK such that it gave RTCM corrections on USB port. Then I used pyrtcm library to read the corrections and then appropriately format the readings  for required ROS2 topics
